# Qt 5.10 Can I change variables (manually) during debuging as in Octave?

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, breakpoints

I was  using Octave recently. In Octave I can run my code in debug-mode using breakpoints. When the execution stops at a breakpoint I can go to the Command window and change the value of my variables by hand.

For example my code sets `A=5; B=8;` and I stop at the line `B=8`. In the command Window I can now change A manually to let´s say `10` . I found this quite useful. `5.10`

Now I wonder if there is a similar functionality in Qt creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on a variable value in "Locals" view and enter new value.

[image]